# Cycles: Switch shader node in viewport vs. render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders

When I'm working on my object, I want to see it fully rendered. When I render it, it needs to be almost zero alpha (fully transparent). Can I tell in a shader whether I'm rendering or in viewport?

Comment: Why not switch viewport shading mode to *Solid* or anything else not shaded?

Comment: Ah, good idea. I ought to be able to remember to switch it back before rendering, I hope! :-)